# Opening form from another Project

Tags: c#

I made a project in C#.
I completely copied a form from another project that contains three files into my project directory and added it to the Solution Explorer window. In another form, When I try to call the added form, added form name is not displayed. please Help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I see some red lines in the code. Is Main form in the same namespace (Copy_Form) with Form1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your Namespace in Form1.cs is "Copy_Form".

Go to Main.cs and notice how its using a different Namespace!

To fix the problem, change the Namespace in Main.cs to "Copy_Form", then goto the Main.designer.cs and change the Namespace to "Copy_Form" there as well.

Now build the app (Ctrl + Shift + B). The Main Form will be accessible from Form1.